# mySQL->updating/inserting "compound" records

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `exp_ws_gk_text` (
    `WGT_RID` INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `WGT_PRG_CODE` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `WGT_TEXT` VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `PrimaryKey` (`WGT_RID`)
)

CREATE TABLE `exp_ws_gk_state` (
    `WGS_RID` INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `WGS_TYPE` INT(9) NOT NULL,
    `WGS_STATE` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    `WGS_WGT_RID` INT(9) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `PrimaryKey` (`WGS_RID`),
    INDEX `SecondaryKey` (`WGS_TYPE`, `WGS_STATE`)
)
```

This is how I query the data to be used in a site:

```
SELECT a.wgt_rid id, a.wgt_text text, a.wgt_prg_code prg_code, 
       b.wgs_state state, b.wgs_type type, 
FROM exp_ws_gk_text a, exp_ws_gk_state b
WHERE a.wgt_rid = b.wgs_wgt_rid
```

I present the record with all the data returned. Now, when I want to edit or append a record, how would I save the data correctly if the data got sent from a form with these parameters:

```
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
$prg_code = $_REQUEST['prg_code'];
$state = $_REQUEST['state'];
$crs_type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$text = $_REQUEST['text'];
```

**An insert:**

```
$sql    = "BEGIN; ".
          "    INSERT INTO exp_ws_gk_text (WGT_PRG_CODE, WGT_TEXT) ".
          "      VALUES('".$prg_code."', '".$text."'); " .
          "    INSERT INTO exp_ws_gk_state (WGS_STATE, WGS_TYPE, WGS_WGT_RID) ".
          "      VALUES('".$state."', ".$course_type.", LAST_INSERT_ID()); ".
          "COMMIT;";
$mysql_query($sql);
$sql    = "SELECT WGS_WGT_RID id FROM exp_ws_gk_text WHERE WGS_RID = ".mysql_insert_id();
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$r = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo json_encode(array(
    'id' => $r["id"],
    'prg_code' => $prg_code,
    'state' => $state,
    'type' => $type,
    'text' => $text
));
```

**A delete:**

```
DELETE a, b FROM exp_ws_gk_text a
JOIN exp_ws_gk_state b ON a.WGT_RID = b.wgs_wgt_rid
WHERE a.WGT_RID = :id
```

Comment: i think that you need to first insert the data in to one table and get the reference of last_insert_id and then you can insert data in to another table with your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "UPDATE exp_ws_gk_text a, exp_ws_gk_state b
SET a.WGT_PRG_CODE = ".$prg_code.", a.WGT_TEXT = ".$text.", b.WGS_STATE = ".$state.", b.WGS_TYPE = ".$crs_type."
WHERE
a.WGT_RID = ".$id." AND a.WGT_RID = b.wgs_wgt_rid";
```

Comment: Oh, forgot, how about an INSERT? That is going to have to be done in 2 passes, right?

Comment: Ah never mind, I think I've got it, see edited post.

Comment: Yes, you can do it as you've exposed it as well.